# Twig, how to print a nl2br output in one line

Tags: symfony, twig

I used the nl2br filter like this:

```
{{ knp_pagination_render(requests)|raw|nl2br}}
```

It prints the html object separated by a few line breaks, and I need to print all the objects in one single line.  How can I reach that?

Any help would be great.

Comment: Just don't use `nl2br` then?

Comment: if I don't use nl2br it gives me data with some break lines and I want all in one line.

Comment: Your question is confusing initially. After you comment it became even more confusing. Provide the exact example of data you have and you want to achieve.

Comment: sorry if I don't use nl2br i get html data with line breaks. The nl2br show me the data in one column, so I think that there is some function to transform the data in one line.

Comment: What's your input and what's your desired output?

Comment: my input is a paginatioin hrml data, my desired outpur is all in one line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to override the default pagination template, so you can customize how to generate the underling HTML code.

As [described in the doc](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/templates.md#overriding-default-pagination-template) You can do simply:

```
{{ knp_pagination_render(request, 'MyBundle:Pagination:pagination.html.twig') }}
```

You can copy the current pagination implementation from [here](http://KnpPaginatorBundle:Pagination:sliding.html.twig) and customize it as you need.

This is the default implementation:

```
{# default Sliding pagination control implementation #}

{% if pageCount > 1 %}
<div class="pagination">
    {% if first is defined and current != first %}
        <span class="first">
            <a href="{{ path(route, query|merge({(pageParameterName): first})) }}">&lt;&lt;</a>
        </span>
    {% endif %}

    {% if previous is defined %}
        <span class="previous">
            <a href="{{ path(route, query|merge({(pageParameterName): previous})) }}">&lt;</a>
        </span>
    {% endif %}

    {% for page in pagesInRange %}
        {% if page != current %}
            <span class="page">
                <a href="{{ path(route, query|merge({(pageParameterName): page})) }}">{{ page }}</a>
            </span>
        {% else %}
            <span class="current">{{ page }}</span>
        {% endif %}

    {% endfor %}

    {% if next is defined %}
        <span class="next">
            <a href="{{ path(route, query|merge({(pageParameterName): next})) }}">&gt;</a>
        </span>
    {% endif %}

    {% if last is defined and current != last %}
        <span class="last">
            <a href="{{ path(route, query|merge({(pageParameterName): last})) }}">&gt;&gt;</a>
        </span>
    {% endif %}
</div>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
{{ string | replace({"\\n":""}) }}
```

See [fiddle](http://twigfiddle.com/tyrnz0).